# Blazor localization do not load resource translations

Tags: .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-localization

I have a .NET 6 Bloazor PWA application  where i want to let the customer choose the language for the UI of the app.
I have prepared resource .resx files and set the Default language in Program.cs and set the AddLocalization service, but when i chose the language from the combo element the localized text on the page do not change at all.
Moreover i always see the 'keys' instead their corresponding strings in resurces file; it looks like the system do to find resource files at all.
where am i wrong ?

I used:

(.csproj file)

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

(Program.cs):

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization(Options => Options.ResourcesPath= "ResourceFiles");
var host = builder.Build(); CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("it-IT");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("it-IT");
await host.RunAsync();
```

then i defined the ResourceFiles directory

[image]

with inside Resource.resx , Resources.it.resx with two text records with
(Resources.it.resx and Resources.resx)

```
Name="intro1" value="Benvenuto!"
Name="intro2" value="Grazie per utilizzare la nostra app" `
```

(Resources.en.resx)

```
Name="intro1" value="Welcome!"
Name="intro2" value="Thank you for using our app" `
```

and in addition an empty Resources class to collect resx files and assign later it to IStringLocalizer in the razor page

```
namespace BlazorAppPWAalone.ResourceFiles
{
    public class Resources
    {
    }
}
```

in my page:

```
@using System.Globalization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@inject IStringLocalizer<Resources> Loc

<h1>Language change:</h1>
<select name="lingue" id="idlingua" @bind="sceltaLingua">
  <option value="it-IT">Italiano</option>
  <option value="en-US">Inglese</option>
</select>

<p>
    <b>CurrentCulture</b>: @CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
    <b>CurrentUICulture</b>: @CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture
</p>
<p>@Loc["intro1"], @Loc["intro2"]</p>


@code {
    private string _sceltaLingua;
    public string sceltaLingua
    { 
        get 
        {
            return _sceltaLingua;
        } 
        set 
        {
            _sceltaLingua = value;
            CambiaLingua(_sceltaLingua);
        } 
    }

    private void CambiaLingua(string newlang)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(newlang);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(newlang);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

When i choose the language the @CurrentCulture and  @CurrentUICulture variables show correctly the selected language but @Loc["intro1"], @Loc["intro2"] never change, it always displays default (italian) resource values.

Why ?  where is my code 'bug' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve not done this in WASM yet but in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly#dynamically-set-the-culture-by-user-preference-1) the CultureSelector does not actually set `CurrentCulture` to change the language but sets a key value pair in the browsers local storage and triggers a reload which causes `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and
`DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` to be set to the culture specified in local storage.

And judging from this:

> Always set DefaultThreadCurrentCulture and DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture to the same culture in order to use IStringLocalizer and IStringLocalizer.

just setting `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` will probably not work.

I don´t know if you can just set `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` from the component and reload or if you need to follow the documentations exact approach but that should be easy for you to try out.

Comment: You are right.  it's not enought but i verified you have to set it on start-up of the application. Being a Blazor app the easier place to save the current Culture is Local Storage so that if null you can set (first run) , other wise you read it from there and set it again.